# Is there a way to create an Azure DevOps Task without having to send multiple objects for each value?

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to set --for example-- the title and the team names in one operation instead of doing something like this?

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "from": null,
        "value": "Test of REST functionality"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.State",
        "from": null,
        "value": "New"
    }
]
```

If not, what would be the best way to go about creating a method/functions/class that create the object for the work item I'd like to cerate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no way to do that in one operation. You have to specify the required field values based on your requirement.

You can reference the following samples to create or update the work items using the API.

- [Create a bug in Azure DevOps Services using .NET client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/create-bug-quickstart?view=azure-devops)
- [WorkItemsSample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs)